# Yii CCaptcha "Get New Code" doesn't show

Tags: php, yii, captcha

I have a view which uses renderPartial:

```
$this->renderPartial('MyBankInfo',
array('userEntity'=>$userEntity,
'userAccount'=>$userAccount,
'bonuspaymentmethodlist'=>$bonuspaymentmethodlist,
'modelCaptcha'=>$modelCaptcha)
,false,true);
```

Here's the captcha code in view:

```
<?php $this->widget('CCaptcha',array('clickableImage' => true));  ?>
```

It works when i am using render but not when im rendering it in partial.

There doesn't seem to be any error on my console, when i clicked on the image, the refresh function is called but the image isn't refresh nor does the "Get New Code" link appears.

However when i refresh the page, the image is refreshed (if i clicked on in once).

Is there any particular JS that i need to reload? I've already set the process to true though.